# How to take Performance Numbers using XSLT profiler using visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am planning to take performance number using xslt 2.0 in Visual studio-2012 with xslt-Profiler.  However I getting `System.Xml.Xsl.XslTransformException: 'result-document' is not a recognized extension element`.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's `XslCompiledTransform` is an XSLT 1.0 processor. See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-2.0/info for XSLT 2.0 processors by third parties.

Comment: The error message you get cites `System.Xml.Xsl.XslTransformException`. I don't think Saxon throws exceptions of that class. I don't think the XSLT profiler in VS is meant to work with third party XSLT processors like Saxon. If you want to profile Saxon then the Java version of it allows ways of doing that, see http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!using-xsl/performanceanalysis. I am not sure how to profile Saxon for .NET, maybe someone else can help.